# How to add more supported machine types to QEMU?

Tags: qemu, libvirt, openstack-nova

I have an Openstack Pike deployment in [Cloudlab](https://www.cloudlab.us/), and it is using QEMU version `2.10.1(Debian 1:2.10+dfsg-0ubuntu3.8~cloud1)`.

I wanted to replace the QEMU with [this version](https://github.com/changyeon/qemu/tree/profiler) which enables support for monitoring through QMP. I configured using : `./configure --target-list=x86_64-softmmu` and compiled the binary `qemu-system-x86_64` but when I check the supported machine types it was missing some of the machine types which were present in the original binary:

```
pc-i440fx-zesty      Ubuntu 17.04 PC (i440FX + PIIX, 1996)
pc-i440fx-yakkety    Ubuntu 16.10 PC (i440FX + PIIX, 1996)
pc-i440fx-xenial     Ubuntu 16.04 PC (i440FX + PIIX, 1996)
pc-i440fx-wily       Ubuntu 15.04 PC (i440FX + PIIX, 1996)
pc-i440fx-trusty     Ubuntu 14.04 PC (i440FX + PIIX, 1996)
ubuntu               Ubuntu 17.10 PC (i440FX + PIIX, 1996) (alias of pc-i440fx-artful)
pc-i440fx-artful     Ubuntu 17.10 PC (i440FX + PIIX, 1996) (default)
pc-i440fx-2.9        Standard PC (i440FX + PIIX, 1996)
pc-q35-zesty         Ubuntu 17.04 PC (Q35 + ICH9, 2009)
pc-q35-yakkety       Ubuntu 16.10 PC (Q35 + ICH9, 2009)
pc-q35-xenial        Ubuntu 16.04 PC (Q35 + ICH9, 2009)
pc-q35-artful        Ubuntu 17.10 PC (Q35 + ICH9, 2009)
pc-q35-2.9           Standard PC (Q35 + ICH9, 2009)
```

So when I tried to deploy a test VM with Openstack, it gave me the error:

```
libvirtError: internal error: process exited while connecting to monitor: 2019-01-24T19:41:51.292121Z qemu-system-x86_64: -enable-kvm: unsupported machine type
```

and when I changed the machine type to one of the available ones `hw_machine_type = x86_64=pc-i440fx-1.6` , it gave me this error:

```
libvirtError: internal error: qemu unexpectedly closed the monitor: qemu: could not load PC BIOS 'bios-256k.bin'
```

So after looking around for the error I just created a symlink:

```
sudo ln -sf /usr/share/seabios/bios-256k.bin /usr/share/qemu/bios.bin
```

But then it gives the following error:

```
libvirtError: internal error: qemu unexpectedly closed the monitor: Could not open option rom 'kvmvapic.bin': No such file or directory
```

So I am thinking that maybe I should just use the original machine type, and I want to know how do we add more supported machine types when building QEMU? I guess it must be one of the configuration options but I haven't been able to find it.

Answer (score 1):

Adding new machine types is done by modifying the QEMU source code when building it. As you might guess from the machine names, these are specific to the Ubuntu QEMU version, so they will have been added via patches in the Ubuntu QEMU package. The machines will basically be like the stock upstream pc-i440fx-n.n and pc-q32-n.n ones, but will have properties set so that they behave "like the version of QEMU that shipped in this release of Ubuntu". This is important for compatibility when migrating virtual machines. It may also have minor differences like what BIOS blob filenames it looks for: Ubuntu/Debian might also have patched QEMU to edit things like the directory searched for BIOS blobs.

The other QEMU version you link to is based on upstream QEMU, so it doesn't have those Ubuntu specific patches that enable the Ubuntu specific machine types. (It's also based on an older version of QEMU so will be missing various fixes for security issues discovered after that release, so be cautious! Check whether any of the non-patched security issues between 2.8.1 and now are important for your use case.)

You can either press forward with trying to adjust your machine configuration to work with the non-Ubuntu machine type. (Use the most recent pc-i440fx-n.n it has -- 1.6 is pretty elderly and it ought to have a 2.8.) Or alternatively you can try to rebase the patches that add the QMP-monitoring feature so that they apply to the Ubuntu QEMU sources. For anything resembling production I think the latter is probably the way to go because of the no-security-fixes problem with using somebody's random development tree, but it may not be easy.

Comment: Is there a way I can find those patches from Ubuntu for the machine types?
I am not worried about the security aspect since these machines are being used for research in a private environment. I just want to be able to use the QMP profiler with my Openstack VMs. I will try the recent machine type versions.

Comment: The patches will be in the Ubuntu source package.